# How do I identify why a webpack bundle was loaded?

Tags: webpack

I am working on reducing the amount of code that we are loading that is not being used, according to Lighthouse.

I've split my [webpack](/questions/tagged/webpack) bundle in small pieces using the following logic:

```
splitChunks: {
  cacheGroups: {
    default: false,
  },
  chunks: 'all',
  maxAsyncRequests: 60,
  maxInitialRequests: 60,
  maxSize: 50_000,
  minSize: 20_000,
},
```

I was expecting that this will reduce how many scripts we load, though it had no effect on the amount of unused code that webpack loads: on average, a loaded bundle has more than 95% of its code not used.

How do I identify the code path that causes these chunks to be loaded?

Comment: Have you tried tools like bundle analyzer and dependency graph? I think it might be helpful here.

Comment: Unless I am not thinking about it right, using dependency graph does not answer the question of why bundle X is loaded when I am viewing page Y.

Comment: My thinking was that since webpack does Tree Shaking while building, Bundle X is being loaded on Page Y because there might be a reference to Bundle X on page Y and dependency graph can help to visualize this.